# Laravel 5.3 socialite installation error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-socialite

I am trying to install laravel socialite plugin using this command

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

But i will get the following error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages
>
> Problem 1
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
>       - laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
>       - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/http v5.4.0
>       - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].

Laravel version: 5.3

php version 7.0.13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to install latest socialite package for the Laravel 5.3 which needs at least Laravel 5.4.

```
Problem 1 - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by
```

Try to install on Laravel 5.4.

Check this:

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/contracts": "~5.4",
        "illuminate/http": "~5.4",
        "illuminate/support": "~5.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "league/oauth1-client": "~1.0"
    },
```

It requires 5.4

OR

As an alternative you can use the older version of socialite which is compatible with Laravel 5.3 like:

```
composer require laravel/socialite 2.0
```

Comment: Butmy  laravel version is 5.3

Comment: Then you have to use socialite 2.0 which is compatible with Laravel ~5.0 https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/composer.json

Comment: does any compatible version of socilaite plugin is available??

Comment: How  can i install the version 2.0?

Comment: In your composer.json file, in "require" key, add: 
"laravel/socialite": "2.0" and then run composer install command

Comment: Thanks let me try it

Comment: when running composer install  i will get nothing to update or install message

Comment: Make sure you don't have that package installed already.. is socialite is there in that composer.json file?

Comment: Nop there is no  previous versions of socialite plugin

Comment: Strange, it should work. Can you try same on fresh laravel 5.3?

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have socialite package already in vendor directory.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfect. I couldn't update Laravel version, so I installed version 2.0 of Socialite.

Comment: @brunoramonalmeida, glad I could helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

For laravel 5.3

Run following command and this will work for you.

```
composer require laravel/socialite ^2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help

```
composer require laravel/socialite "^3.2.0"
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite#installation

Answer (score 0):

composer require laravel/socialite "~3.2.0"